# How should I be declaring and exporting modules?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using the `secure` and `crud` modules with my app, and I've added them to application.conf as described in the [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/guide7).  However, when I start my app, it generates a warning:

`Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated.  Use dependencies.yml instead. (module.crud)`

The modules then work while in dev mode, but when I deploy to my server (with `play war` etc), 
I get this:

`13:55:40,662 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.crud)`

`13:55:40,662 ERROR ~ Module crud will not be loaded because /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/pat/WEB-INF/modules/crud does not exist`

So, two questions: why aren't my modules getting exported, and how do I declare them in dependencies.yml?  I've looked at the [dependency page in the docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/dependency), and I admit that I don't really get what's going on there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to set up modules in play 1.2+ is to use the --with keyword when you create your app.

For example

```
play new myapp --with crud,secure
```

The output of the generated dependencies.yml is

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - play -> secure
    - play -> crud
```

Comment: Very nice!  It would be beautiful if this were included in the tutorial.  Is there a way to do this with an existing application?  Not that adding two lines to dependencies.yml is that hard, but still :)

Comment: not that I know of. It is probably easier to just create a new application with `play new` and then copying the dependencies.yml file across to your existing application.

Answer (score 4):

OK, solved it.  I added

```
- play -> crud
- play -> secure
```

to dependencies.yml, and deleted the relevant lines in application.conf.  Then I ran `play dependencies` to copy the modules into my app.  Play starts without any warnings, and the modules export to the WAR file correctly.  I hope this helps people!