# Play Framework - How to add a module in existing application

Tags: java, playframework

I came across new play module and I would like  add it in my existing play application. Is there any play command associated for this action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a command for it.
Just run `play install #your-module-name#`

Also read the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/modules) carefully.

Comment: This is only a partial answer to the question. Play `install` will download and deploy the module in play, not in the application. to use the module in the application, you still need to edit dependenties.yml and run `play dependencies` on the application.

Answer (score 4):

Per Codemwnci at my question ([How should I be declaring and exporting modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261698/how-should-i-be-declaring-and-exporting-modules)), a better way to add modules is when you create your app, like so:

```
play new myapp --with crud,secure
```

This adds the applications to `dependencies.yml`, which is the preferred place for them these days.  If you already have an existing app, add for example

```
- play -> crud
- play -> secure
```

to `dependencies.yml` and run `play dependencies` to install.  (Followed by `play eclipsify` etc if you're using Eclipse.)