# How to install multiple modules and setup dependencies with Play Framework

Tags: module, dependencies, log4j, installation, playframework

I am trying to install BetterLogs and log4Play modules in my application.
Log4Play seems to work in chrome but I don't seem to be able to enhance the logs with better logs.
I installed/configured  the modules with the following:

```
play install betterlogs
play install log4play
```

Added this to the dependencies.yml

```
require:
    - play -> log4play 0.5
    - play -> betterlogs 1.0
```

and this to my application.conf

```
module.log4play=${play.path}/modules/log4play-0.5
module.betterlogs=${play.path}/modules/betterlogs-1.0

betterlogs.prefix=[%relativeFile:%line] %method() ::
```

Am I doing something wrong in the dependency declaration?

---

**Update:** Fixed by doing the following:

- removed the modules entries from the application.conf
- ran play dependencies with the following dependecies.yml

```
    
require:
    - play -> log4play 0.5
    - play -> betterlogs 1.0
    - provided -> mylib 1.0

repositories:
  - provided:
      type:       local
      artifact:   "${application.path}/jar/[module]-[revision].jar"
      contains:
        - provided -> *
```

- play clean
- play eclipsify -deps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add the following in dependencies.yml file and run `play dependencies` in your application root folder.

```
require:
    - play -> log4play 0.5
    - play -> betterlogs 1.0
```

Comment: I ran the command and get the following error when running the app:   he file {module:log4play-0.5}/app/controllers/log4play/Log4Play.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Log4Play is already defined.          Is the module definition required in the application.conf if defined in the dependencies.yml?

Comment: Problem above fixed by removing the module lines from the application.conf and rerunning play dependencies. However betterLogs modules does not seem to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of a lot of the dependency handling at project creation with the following (from [How should I be declaring and exporting modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261698/how-should-i-be-declaring-and-exporting-modules/7262059#7262059)):

```
play new myapp --with module1,module2,etc
play dependencies
```

This is assuming you've already `play install`ed the modules you need.